# How to repeat this code

Tags: javascript, html, loops

so i have this code that shows 2 images and a nice slide effect.
But after showing both images its stops.
How ever i want it to repeat, so from 1-2-1-2 like that.

I read something about this:

```
    boolean exitLoop = false;
while (!exitLoop) { 
    // insert code here
}
```

But it wont work for me.. Atleast i dont really know how to add it.
Can someone make my code repeat? Here is my code:

```
    <!doctype html>
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    var slideimages = new Array() ;
    slideimages[0] = new Image() ;
    slideimages[0].src = "Slide1.JPG"; 
    slideimages[1] = new Image() ;
    slideimages[1].src = "Slide2.JPG";

    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="slidr-img" style="dislay: block">
<!--    <img data-slidr="one" src="Slide1.JPG" id="slide" />-->
        <img data-slidr="one" src="Slide1.JPG" />
<img data-slidr="two" src="Slide2.JPG" />
</div> 

<script src="slidr.min.js"></script>
<script>

slidr.create('slidr-img', { 
    transition: 'cube',
    controls: 'none'
}).auto(1000);

</script>    

<script type="text/javascript">
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Thanks already!
Kind regards, Raul.

Comment: In _JavaScript_ we don't explicitly state the type when defining variables, use `var exitLoop = false;`

Comment: Can you put it in my code if you have time? I am not an expert at this.. Just learning! Thanks for helping already sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [doc](http://www.bchanx.com/slidr#docs);

```
// Add horizontal slides with default linear transition.
// **The extra "one" allows the slidr to circle back and loop infinitely.
s.add('h', ['one', 'two', 'three', 'one']);
```

Please read the comment line with star.

You can replace your slidr creation with this:

```
slidr.create('slidr-img', { 
    transition: 'cube',
    controls: 'none'
})
.add('h', ['one', 'two', 'one'])
.auto(1000);
```

Comment: Could you make my code alright? I dont know where to add this !

Comment: Accepted, sorry for the long wait.